# input sanitization VS validation

Tags: php

I've implemented input validation on all of my input data using php (as well as js on the front-end). I'm type casting where I can, validating stuff like emails against a regex, making sure dropdown values are only ones I'm expecting and also in many cases where I'm expecting only a string I have a regex that runs that only allows letters, numbers and spaces. Anything that doesn't meet these rules results in the form failing validation and no sql queries are run.

With that said if my form passes validation I'm making the assumption that it's safe for input in to my db (which I'm doing via pdo) and then escaped on output.

So with that said why do I need input sanitization?

Comment: I'd say that you are following an accepted method. Sanitization and validation (together) is not always necessary. Although, I'm a fan of defense in depth, so I'd probably do both. But "rejecting known bad" and "accepting known good" is also considered acceptable. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have very strict validation server-side, you don't need to sanatize. Eg. validating a string against /^[a-z0-9]{5,25}$/ will not need any sanitization (removing non alphanumeric characters will not make any sense, since they should not be able to pass anyway).

Just make sure you can validate all data, and if that's impossible (e.g. with html it tends to be a bit difficult), you can use escaping strategies or things like html purifier.

For a good overview on escaping strategies for XSS prevention:
see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

For an idea of different security threats:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Yes I'm well versed in the content on owasp. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need both. Validating input data is easily beaten at the client side, but it's useful for legitimate users who aren't trying to hack you.
Sanitize the data (all the data, whether it's input data or something straight from your DB that you think you should be able to trust) before putting it into your database.

Even if you 100% trust your validation and do it on the server side (where, in theory, people shouldn't be able to mess with the data), it's still worth using some form of sanitizing because it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: Even if you're super-confident about your validation, why take the risk?

Comment: True, I'd like to be as safe as possible so this question was asked in order to clear up my confusion.The only difference I see between validation and sanitization is that validation returns true or false when testing input whereas sanitization actually replaces the unwanted characters. I'm going to end up validating against a regex and then sanitize them with the same regex but instead use preg_replace.Just seems a bit backward.

Comment: One context where sanitization could come in to it's own is where I can't validate aggressively i.e. a free text field where the user can enter non alphanumeric chars...then I can see the use in sanitization